# Using .css('top'); in IE and Safari that doesn't have an explicit top value returns 'auto'; Any way to get a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an absolutely positioned [element] such that in the CSS, I've explicitly set its left property to -9999px.  I have not set the top property.  I cannot set it, since I want the element to "stay" where it is in the DOM (even though it's out of the document flow)

When I call [element].css('top') in jQuery, FF returns a value.  IE and Safari return 'auto'.  Is there a way to get the top value in IE/Safari?  The CSS top value seems to be different than the top value coming from .offset().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto` is a valid setting for the `top:` setting, so no, that's what it actually is. I'll also throw in that Chrome shows `auto` as well. You'll have to use `.offset().top`.

It's also worth noting that I'm getting 10 for both `.css('top')` and `.offset().top` in Firefox using http://jsfiddle.net/HVxtd/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('.elm').offset().top
```

Comment: Ah, so that's the correct way to get the correct top value.  Thank you.